# Authentication for Azure REST Api

Tags: rest, azure

I want to communicate with Azure only with REST Api and without any sdk component - communicate to the new ARM
how can I get the Bearer token for the authentication? i saw that all the examples use the SDK for that

Answer (score 0):

To get a token for authorization, you need to install the Active Directory Authentication Library into your project. The easiest way to do this is to use the [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory).

Use this code to get the token:

```
public static string GetAToken()
{
  var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/{tenantId or tenant name}");
  var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId: "{application id}", clientSecret: {application password}");
  var result = authenticationContext.AcquireToken(resource: "https://management.core.windows.net/", clientCredential:credential);

  if (result == null) {
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to obtain the JWT token");
  }

  string token = result.AccessToken;

  return token;
}
```

There are more details and code examples at [Authenticating Azure Resource Manager requests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790557.aspx).

Comment: I am using java and not c#

Comment: It helps to specify that in your question :-) ...For Java - see Jim Spring's post at http://innerdot.com/azure/authenticating-to-azure-resource-manager-using-java